# Familiars and Skill Tricks

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, familiars

The rules for Familiars state that they use either the master's skill ranks or their own, whichever is higher. However, skill tricks did not exist when these rules were written. If a master spends skill points to purchase Skill Tricks, is that the same as the master putting a "rank" into a skill trick that the Familiar can then also use?

For example, if the master has Swift Concentration and the feat Spell-Linked Familiar, can he give the familiar the Augment Familiar spell and allow the familiar to cast it on itself and concentrate on it as a swift action every round for as long as the familiar wants the spell to be active (or until it takes damage and fails a Concentration check)? Augment Familiar normally has a Duration of Concentration + 1 round per caster level. Or if that does not work (because the familiar does not have a familiar of its own to target), any other spell with a duration of Concentration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Skill Trick rules from *Complete Scoundrel* don‘t say that a familiar can use a trick it‘s master has learned, so by RAW they can‘t. On the other hand, I wouldn‘t have problems with familiars using their master‘s tricks. Familiars use their master‘s skill ranks, so why not also give them access to their master‘s skill tricks - which are acquired at the expense of skill points/ranks?

Of course, you have to keep in mind the limited use of Skill Tricks.

> Unless otherwise noted, a skill trick can be performed only once per
> encounter (or once per minute, for scenes that don’t involve combat or
> other conflict).

Due to these restrictions, your example of a familiar using Swift Concentration in consecutive rounds would not work.

Also, a very strict DM would probably argue that a familiar can‘t cast Augment Familiar on itself, since the target entry of the spell is "Your familiar". But I really see no reason not to allow that.